# Google Sheets Complex Filter

Tags: google-sheets, filtering

thanks for reading this post first of all. I've been struggling with this task and not making much progress after all the research I've done online.

I have the sheet below which contains thousands of rooms from supermarket stores.

[image: BEFORE]

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Get the total area of each room per **Location Number** (every store has a different location number)
2. When room duplicates are found (as in the example below), only the room with the highest number in **Phase Order** must be used.
3. Some rooms may be split in two (like on rows 9 and 10). In these cases I need to add up both room areas.

This is the result I'm after, I hope it all made sense and thanks again for reading it. It's been a bit of a challenge. Any help or steer in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

[image: AFTER]

This is a link to a [sample of the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lgvCTfeS_juNjrEpPj0fnCzj1OmtP6Z1/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: It would help if you could provide this sample data in tabular form here or a demo sheet would suffice too..

Comment: @floretti, I managed to create a Formula that will accomplish your 3 goals. However, I can only make it work by excluding the `Room Phase` column. Will that work for you?

Comment: Or to change the column manually `E` to `Double Welcome Gate` in the raw data or inside the `Query`. If that is okay with you I can add an answer with some options for you.

Comment: Good point, @rockinfreakshow, that was not smart from me. I think Giselle already found something that can work but if not I'll definitely post the demo sheet.

Comment: @GiselleValladares That would be amazing and yes, the Room Phase column can be ignored. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
=sortn(query({A2:E},"Select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3),Col4,Col5 Where Col2<>'' group by Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5 order by Col4 desc label sum(Col3) ''"),9^9,2,2,1)
```

[image]

***Updated formula***:

```
=index(let(Σ,sortn(query({if(len(A2:A),A2:A&"|"&B2:B,),C2:D},"Select Col1,sum(Col2),Col3 Where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col3 order by Col3 desc label sum(Col2) ''"),9^9,2,1,1), {split(index(Σ,,1),"|"),index(Σ,,2),index(Σ,,3)}))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm amazed with this one, it's short and cool.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I tried it but unfortunately I'm getting only one room per location number. I've tried to remove the location number grouping but it broke the formula. Any suggestions to show all rooms per location? Btw, I added a link to a decent sample of the data with multiple locations.

Comment: added updated formula version in the answer. please do test it out.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Total wiz! Thanks so much, I'll test it out.

Comment: It works, thanks again @rockinfreakshow. Life saver!

Answer (score 2):

A bit longwinded (and old school) but does seem to work.

`=query({query({query({A1:E},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, max(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col2,Col1,Col3")},"select Col1, Col2, Sum(Col3) group by Col1,Col2,Col4 label Sum(Col3) 'Room Area' format Sum(Col3) '#0.00'"),query({query({query({A1:E},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, max(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col2,Col1,Col3")},"select Col1, Col2, Sum(Col3), Col4 group by Col1,Col2,Col4 label Sum(Col3) 'Room Area',Col4 'Phase' format Sum(Col3) '#0.00'")},"select Col4"),arrayformula(vlookup(query({query({query({A1:E},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, max(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col2,Col1,Col3")},"select Col1, Col2, Sum(Col3), Col4 group by Col1,Col2,Col4 label Sum(Col3) 'Room Area',Col4 'Phase' format Sum(Col3) '#0.00'")},"select Col4"),{D1:E},2,0))})`

**Results**

[image: Results]

Comment: I didn't know how to make it work with a `vlookup` it's amazing. I think I learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one, is similar to @Tedinoz. I hardcoded `Double Welcome Gate` for the `Phase Room` column.

```
=QUERY(
       QUERY(A2:E,"select A, B, C, MAX(D), 'Double Welcome Gate' group by B, A, C, 'Double Welcome Gate'"),
       "Select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3), Col4, Col5 group by Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5 
       label Col1'Location Number', Col2'Room Name', sum(Col3)'Room Area', Col4'Phase Order', Col5'Phase Room' 
       format Sum(Col3) '#0.00'"
 )
```

I made some test in case there are multiple Locations too, to make sure it works properly. Using this as a sample data:

[image: sample data]

And this result:

[image: result]

Or use this formula to completely disregard the last `Room phase` column:

```
=QUERY(
       QUERY(A2:D23,"select A, B, C, MAX(D) group by B, A, C"),
       "Select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3), Col4 group by Col1, Col2, Col4 
       label Col1'Location Number', Col2'Room Name', sum(Col3)'Room Area', Col4'Phase Order' 
       format Sum(Col3) '#0.00'"
 )
```

Like this:

[image: result 2]